# SQL Server 2005 - how can I delay the first replication alert?

Tags: alert, merge-replication

I have SQL Server 2005 Merge replication set up, and a single subscriber which is setup as a pull subscription. It runs on a schedule of once per minute.

I would like to be alerted if the SQL Server replication agent has been failing for a certain period of time or for a certain number of attempts. For example, if it fails and then starts working again very soon afterwards, that’s fine – I don’t want to be alerted.

However, if it’s still failing after 5 minutes or 5 times, then I would like to be alerted.

I’ve looked at the “delay between responses” setting, but it seems this will always send the initial alert, and the delay only takes effect for any subsequent alerts.

Additionally, I want to know if a single merge takes more than 5 minutes. So if it has been running for 5 minutes or more, we get an alert.